# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error An unknown FastCGI error occurred

Tags: python, django, iis, django-rest-framework, deployment

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
An unknown FastCGI error occurred

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    Django Handler
Error Code     0x8007010b
Requested URL      http://localhost:8000/
Physical Path      F:\SMSBUILDPROJECT\SMS_PRODUCT
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

More Information:
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

294807
```

I am trying to deploy Django application on IIS server. I stuck on for this issues.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to look at your logs for your web server and also the service running your app locally . Likely your Django app is unable to serve your request due to [something], but without seeing your logs it is almost impossible to state what that [something] is

Comment: You should use HttpPlatformHandler to run Python based web apps on IIS, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/ that rules out all possible issues caused by `wfastcgi`.

Answer (score -1):

1)Add the site with your project root path in iis.

2)Select site-> Doble clcik handler mappings. Click “Add Module Mapping…” from the actions selection on the right.

3)Set request path to * and Module to FastCgiModule.

set executable:

C:\Python39\Scripts\python.exe|C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

4)Now go back to the server node and select the fast cgi module.

Add below environment variable:

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = “path to your settings”

WSGI_HANDLER = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()

PYTHONPATH = “path to your app root folder e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\djangosite”

5)Assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site root folder and python folder.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-fastcgi-handler

Comment: From the link you referred to, you can see that FastCGI is not recommended any more. So, why left an answer with it?